# ts-jest: declared namespace(.d.ts) shows 'is not defined' ReferenceError when run the test

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Running typescript with ts-jest, the app runs ok in the browser but shows `ReferenceError: R is not defined` erro when run the test.

The file structure:

```
|--app
|   |--job.ts
|--api
|   |--R.d.ts
|--tests
|   |--job.test.ts
```

and the files:

```js
//job.ts
export default class Job{
    private static cmd:R.P.CMD

    constructor(){
        Job.cmd=R.P.getCMD()
    }
    //....
}
```

and the corresponding test file is:

```js
// job.test.ts
import { describe, expect, test, jest, beforeEach } from '@jest/globals';
import Job from '../app/job'

describe('Test Job',()=>{
    test('job init',()=>{
        let job = new Job()
        //....test code
    })
})
```

the R.d.ts is:

```js
declare namespace R{
    //....
}
declare namespace R.P{
    function getCMD(): MyInterface
//...
}
```

for the configs,

```
//jest.config.js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
export default {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$": "$1",
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.{ts|tsx}?$": [
            "ts-jest",
            {
                allowJs: true,
                useESM: true,
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

and in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019",                            
    "moduleResolution": "Node",                
    "baseUrl": "./",           
    "types": [
      "./api/R"
    ],                                

    "allowJs": true,            
    "sourceMap": true,            
    "outDir": "js",              
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,            
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  },
  "files": [
    "./api/R.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": ["./app/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules","**/*.test.ts","./tests/"]
}
```

I tried to import the `R.d.ts` file in `job.test.ts`: `import  '../api/R.d.ts'` but still the same error.
I read in the [doc](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/babel7-or-ts) about Babel7 don't support namespace, but I'm not using babel, the packasges I'm using are:

```
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
```

Update:
the `R.d.ts` is for a js library:

```
|--app
|   |--job.ts
|--api
|   |--R.d.ts
|   |--r-api.js
|--tests
|   |--job.test.ts
```

Jest can find the `R.d.ts` file (because I can use`jest.mock()` and `import '../api/R.d.ts'`, but seems it is not beable to understand the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the right way to do it but at least my tests can run without `R is not defined` now, so here is the 'solution':

1. create a mock file under `api`: `/api/__mocks__/R.d.ts`

```js
declare namespace R{
    //...
}
declare namespace R.P{
    function getCMD(): any
//...
}
```

2. use a reference tag for the mocked .d.ts file in the test file: `/// <reference types='../api/__mocks__/R.d.ts'/>`
3. still in the test file,

```js
global['R'] = {
 P: {
    getCMD: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => { }),
   }
}
```

4. set `isolatedModules:true` in `jest.config.json`